# NPE Error inflating class fragment: NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

When I create a new navigation drawer activity in Android Studio, the basic example runs perfectly. I've changed a few lines to integrate Material Design and v4 - v7 support, and consequently the app breaks. I also included in some lines of basic code from Firebase that does a simple auth with Google+.

Starting the app returns a runtime exception, and  "error inflating class fragment" message.

I'm guessing that the NPE is coming from the view not being inflated, but I have no idea how that is happening.

Below is my logcat, my activities, and my layouts. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

**Logcat:**

```
11-24 16:29:26.735    6127-6127/com.starkenglish E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.starkenglish, PID: 6127
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.starkenglish/com.starkenglish.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.starkenglish.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.starkenglish.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:101)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at com.starkenglish.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:110)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To keep this post clean, I have posted my code as GIST on github.

- **MainActivity.java:**
  https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/a94291edaf02b0b236d3
- **NavigationDrawerFragment.java:**
  https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/92bb583f14604b68b34d
- **fragment_main.xml:**
  https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/d1bda8b3c99d47e0257c
- **fragment_navigation_drawer.xml:**
  https://gist.github.com/markbratanov/5f5e334e40e253736e49

If there is missing code / files please let me know and I'll include it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

your main activity extends FragmentActivity, and in order to get an actionBar

which is listed in your `NavigationDrawerFragment line 101`, just like the error says

```
   mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity().getActionBar().getThemedContext(), <== this is the null part
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));
```

you need to extend the ActionBarActivity from the app compat

quote from the documentation

> ActionBarCompat contains one Activity class which all of your Activity
>   classes should extend: ActionBarActivity. This class itself extends
>   from FragmentActivity so you can continue to use Fragments in your
>   application.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've changed, 

`public class MainActivity extends Activity` to `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity` in MainActivity.java 

Still receiving same error, am I not understanding you?

Comment: can you move the part i pasted in my code to onActivityCreated rather than in onCreateView

Comment: Doesn't work either. 

I've noticed that when I change the styles.xml back to the original template, it works fine. It's when I try to use the new material design appcompat that it fails?

Comment: can you post those xmls ?